# How can I get this Play/Pause Button to work successfully in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this little push-button situation that works in Chrome but not on Safari. I've tried experimenting with autoplay in various parts of this but wasn't lucky. What am I missing here? Please note, I didn't have a sound posted online to share here. I was originally using a Base64 encoded sound file. I will edit this if I'm able to find a shorter one, but the editor here in SO was limiting my post with that included.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Audio Play and Pause</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <audio id="audioElement" preload="auto">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <button id="playPauseButton" onmousedown="playAudio()" onmouseup="pauseAudio()" ontouchstart="playAudio()" ontouchend="pauseAudio()">Play/Pause</button>

  <script>
    function playAudio() {
      document.getElementById("audioElement").play();
    }

    function pauseAudio() {
      document.getElementById("audioElement").pause();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's a link to a JS Fiddle, if it helps. TIA.

https://jsfiddle.net/anonymouspenguin/kevhq7x1/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to debug in Safari, but when I'm in Google Chrome, I click the elipses (3 vertical dot icon), choose Setup, then chose Developer Tools.

Go to Console > Clear Console > click your button

I get this error.  The two attributes onmouseup and ontouchpad in your button tag are conflicting with the others.  Remove them.  Once you get the play working, find the next error and keep going.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted
> by a call to pause().

---

Rather than having the attributes in the button HTML tag itself, you could try this:

```
const button = document.getElementById("playPauseButton");

button.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  document.getElementById("audioElement").play();
});

button.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  document.getElementById("audioElement").pause();
});
```

Comment: Activate the developer mode – Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Develop > Show Error Console. Close the tab

Comment: Also, because you did not include the mp3 in your jsfiddle as an absolute file path (public link), http:://somesite.com/sound.mp3, the play won't work.  You have it has a local relative file path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605845/onmouseup-and-onclick-events-conflicting

Comment: You could try toggling.  Click Play > label of button changes to "Pause" > Click Pause > label of button changes to Play ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918146/play-and-pause-audio-with-the-same-button-please

Comment: Hi @MacGyver, I appreciate the above. Unfortunately (unless I'm mistaking you) I'd like to have the button only play audio while it's held down. It might be silly, but I think it's necessary. If that's not what you're suggesting, please let me know! Thanks! Edit: I forgot to mention that I have tried using a remote path in the fiddle; it'll work in Chrome but not Safari

Comment: I added some additional code in the answer you could try.  If you put an alert("play") in the play function and alert("pause") in the pause function, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for the additional help—I gave this a whirl and I seem to only be able to get it to alert me for plays